# Disable checkbox select on row click in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, client-side

I'm using jqGrid in my client side development. The truth is that I didn't choose it, it was integrated by other developer in entry development level and now there it is late to do something about that.

There is some functionality that I'm trying to change. I have a column of checkboxes and checkboxes are also selected on row click. I want this to work in another way - there must be no connection between checkbox and row state - so I want to disable checkbox select on row click. Is there any way to do this using the plugin?

```
$(this.options.grid).jqGrid({
                    height: 'auto',
                    width: width,
                    shrinkToFit: true,
                    colNames: columns.colNames,
                    colModel: columns.colModel,
                    rowNum: pageSize,
                    rowList: pageSizeValues,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    multiselect: true,
                        multiboxonly: true,
                        deepempty: true,
                        subGrid: false,
                    scrollrows: true,
                    altRows: true,
                    altclass: 'ui-widget-content-alt-row',
                    datatype: 'clientSide',
                    pager: pager,
                    toppager: false,
                    sortname: this.options.sortByVal,
                            sortorder: this.options.sortDirectionVal,
                            sortable: true,
                            jsonReader: reader,
                            editurl: 'clientArray',
                            beforeSelectRow: function(rowId, e) {
                        return true;
                    },
                    onSelectRow: function(rowId, status) {
                        return true;
                    },
```

Comment: Have you tried using onSelectRow method ??

Comment: What exactly? I thought about adding functionality that changes the checkbox state back to previous (before the row click), but it seems as not the best of solutions.

Comment: Please do provide a fiddle . Helps in helping you .

Comment: Well, it's a problem because the values are taken from ajax request. But I update the code in original message